# Query on BooleanFields using string representations of the fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

How can I filter on the boolean fields of a model, given a string representation of the attribute, taken to mean true for that attribute?

As an example, given:

```
class MealBooking(models.Model):

    breakfast = models.BooleanField()
    lunch = models.BooleanField()
    dinner = models.BooleanField()


meal = "breakfast"
```

How can I filter on all MealBookings containing `True` for the field represented by `meal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
MealBooking.objects.filter(**{meal: True})
```

We thus first create a dictionary. If `meal` is for example `'breakfast'`, the dictionary will look like `{ 'breakfast': True }`.

Then we unpack the dictionary to named parameters, by adding two asterisks (`**`) in front. This thus means that if the dictionary is `{ 'breakfast': True }`, we call `.filter(…)` with `.filter(breakfast=True)`.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for. Thank you :)